# C2440 Error, trying to change a const char into a char

Tags: c, character

Alright, so it is a part of an hw, where i can't use strings to aid my problem. I'm a bit stuck since i need to use those character arrays. Any tips on how to solve this?

```
int main()
{
struct structure
{
   char name[15];
};

structure ObrLog[2]= 
{
  {"Bambi"},
  {"Cindarella"},
};
ObrLog[1].nazwa="somethingnew"; //error here
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To copy a C string into a buffer, use `memcpy`. Assuming you meant `name` rather than `nazwa`,

```
char newval[] = "somethingnew";

// in a function
memcpy(ObrLog[1].name, newval, min(strlen(newval) + 1, sizeof(ObrLog[1].name));
ObrLog[1].name[14] = '\0';  // just to be sure the name is NUL-terminated
```

where the definition of `min` is left as an exercise to the reader. The `+1` is there to account for the implicit NUL at the end of `newval`.

Comment: Might just go ahead and use `15` as third argument to `memcpy` (since it seems forbidden to use `strlen`)

Comment: @anatolyg: that exhibits undefined behavior because it copies bytes beyond the end of `newval`.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot modify the character array like that. You need to use [strcpy](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strcpy/) for that and be aware of buffer overflows. ( Assuming a typo of `nazwa` instead of `name` )

```
 strcpy(ObrLog[1].name, "somethingnew");
```

Comment: But be wary of allocated space. Since your second string is longer than your first, you will get very unpositive results.

Comment: but this uses the string.h, which im trying to avoid. Any other suggestions?

Comment: @coolbartek - Try writing one your own that copies byte by byte from source to destination.

Comment: @drdwilcox - What ? I don't understand what you meant. Array size of 15 is sufficient to hold either "Bambi" or "Cindarella" or "somethingnew".